# Move <tr>-Values to another SQL Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

My site is generating a HTML-tr structure with the dataset of a SQL table. Each tr would contain a dataset with each td being a SQL table value, like this:

```
include_once("functions.php");
SQL_Connect();

$queryBestellung = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Bestellung ORDER BY $sortbestellung ASC");

$num = mysql_num_rows($queryBestellung);
$resultproductname  = array();
$resultbestellnummer = array();
$resulturgent = array();
$benutzername  = array();
$resultbestelltesProdukt = array();
$resultbestelltesProduktPakete = array();
$resultbestelltesProduktMenge = array();

if($num)
{
    for ($i = 0; ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryBestellung)); ++$i)
    {
        $resultproductname [$i] = $row["productname"];

        $resultbestellnummer [$i] = $row["bestellnummer"];
        $resulturgent [$i] = $row["urgent"];
        $benutzername [$i] = ( $row ['firstname']." ".$row ['lastname']);

        $resultbestelltesProdukt [$i] = $row["productname"];
        $resultbestelltesProduktPakete [$i] = $row["packages"];
        $resultbestelltesProduktMenge [$i] = $row["quantity"];


    }
}

$arrlength = count($resultbestelltesProdukt);
for ($i = 0; ($i < ($arrlength)); ++$i){
    echo "<tr class='".$resulturgent [$i]."'><td>".$resultbestellnummer [$i]."</td><td>".$benutzername [$i]."</td><td>".$resultbestelltesProdukt [$i]."</td><td>".$resultbestelltesProduktPakete [$i]."</td><td>".$resultbestelltesProduktMenge [$i]."</td><td>".$resulturgent [$i]."</td>
    <td>
    <form  action='Orders.php'  method='post' >
            <div class='buttonDelete'><button class='submit' name='submit' type='submit' value='X'  tabindex='3'></button></div>
            <input name='MOVEOrderForm' type='hidden' value='' />
            <input name='OrderToMOVE' type='hidden' value='".$resultbestellnummer [$i]."' />
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>";

}
```

Now I want to add a function which allows Copying one SQL Dataset (tr) to another table (check the form). My solution looks something like this, but it doesnt work:

```
if (isset($_POST['MOVEOrderForm'])) 
{
    $OrderToMOVE                    =       $_POST["OrderToMOVE"]; 
    include_once("functions.php");  

    SQL_Connect();

    $query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO anKundeVerschickt (bestellnummer, name, urgent, productname, quantity, packages) VALUES (bestellnummer, name, urgent, productname, quantity, packages) FROM bestellung WHERE bestellnummer='$OrderToMOVE' "); 

    mysql_close();  
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to be an INSERT ... SELECT query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

```
$query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO anKundeVerschickt (bestellnummer, name, urgent, productname, quantity, packages) SELECT bestellnummer, name, urgent, productname, quantity, packages FROM bestellung WHERE bestellnummer='$OrderToMOVE' ");
```

Stop using mysql extention it has been deprecated and there is a note to that effect in the manual (it has been there for years). Use PDO or MYSQLI instead.